# ubuntu 14.04 LTS crashes when clicking on launcher icon

Tags: 14.04, crash

I experience reproducible crashes of Ubuntu-14.04 LTS, when clicking on the launcher icon of an application, which is already opened with more than one window. (ex. Thunderbird, Firefox (sometimes LibreOffice Calc))

Ubuntu then crashes back to login closing all programs.

Has anyone an idea how I resolve this issue or experienced something similar?

maybe the xsession-errors are of any help:

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (5664) terminated with status 1
init: indicator-bluetooth main process (5727) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-power main process (5733) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-datetime main process (5741) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-printers main process (5750) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-session main process (5755) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash) main process (9849) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-application main process (5780) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

Comment: Does this occur with system settings?

Comment: no, however it only ever occurs when at least two windows of an app are opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I noticed that it started when I installed unity tweak tool and made some changes in it. I uninstalled it but it didn't help, then I installed it again and I restored all options default. Now switching between many instances of application works fine. So if you had or have unity tweak tool, restoring defaults in tool may be the solution.

Comment: thank you for your help, restoring to default did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried to restore settings only on the one tab (one by one) and I've found that after restoring default settings on the Additional Tab in Windows Manager section, issue has been fixed. Maybe it can help.

Now I can't replay this issue, cos I forgot which settings were on this tab before.